# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare()

Tags: php, javascript, pdo

Al intentar actualizar los datos de usuarios con PHP PDO, me lanza este error en la funcion prepare(). He mirado un rato largo pero no he conseguido ver que error hay con la conexion.

DATABASE.php - Archivo de conexion

```
class Database{

    private $host;
    private $db;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $charset;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->host     = 'xxx';
        $this->db       = 'xxx';
        $this->user     = 'xxx';
        $this->password = "xxx";
        $this->charset  = 'utf8mb4';
    }

    function connect(){
        try{
            $connection = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db . ";charset=" . $this->charset;
            $options = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
            ];
            
            $pdo = new PDO($connection, $this->user, $this->password, $options);
    
            return $pdo;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            print_r('Error connection: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function getDb(){
        if($this->db instanceof PDO){
            return $this->db;
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT_USUARIO.PHP - Vista con textboxes para actualizar los datos. Cojo el id del usuario para hacer el UPDATE.

```
include 'database.php';

  $id=$_GET['id'];

$db = new Database();
  $query = $db->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = ?;");
  $query->execute([$id]);
  $persona = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  print_r ($persona->username);

<div id="contenido">
    <div style="margin: auto; width: 800px; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 5px;">
        <span> <h1>Modificar Producto</h1> </span>
        <br>

      <form action="edit_usuario2.php" method="POST" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 5px;">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET->id;?> ">

        <label>Username: </label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"; value="<?php echo $persona->username; ?>" ><br>
        
        <label>Password: </label>
        <input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $persona->password; ?>"><br>
        
        <label>Id_rol: </label>
        <input type="text" id="id_rol" name="id_rol" value="<?php echo $persona->id_rol; ?>"> </textarea><br>
        
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
     </form>
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

EDIT_USUARIO2 - Pagina donde esta el backend del UPDATE a la BBDD.
ERROR en la sexta línea:
$sentencia = $dbget->prepare($sql);
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

```
include_once 'database.php';

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $id_rol = $_POST['id_rol']; 
    $id = $_POST['id'];


    $db = new Database();
    $dbget = $db->getDb();
    $sql = "UPDATE `usuarios` SET `username` = ?, `password` = ?, `id_rol` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
    $arrParams = array($username, $password, $id_rol, $id);
    $sentencia = $dbget->prepare($sql);
    $sentencia ->execute($arrParams);

    $affectedrows = $sentencia->rowCount();
    if($affectedrows > 0){
        echo "Se ha actualizado correctamente";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que estás intentando usar prepare sobre "XXX"; y un string no tiene método prepare.

```
public function getDb(){
        if($this->db instanceof PDO){
            return $this->db;
        }
    }
```

Devuelves $this->db, que es basicamente el STRING de tu base de datos `$this->db       = 'xxx';`
Te recomiendo guardar el pdo cuando lo creas en el connect y luego devolver eso:

```
class Database{

    private $host;
    private $db;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $charset;
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->host     = 'xxx';
        $this->db       = 'xxx';
        $this->user     = 'xxx';
        $this->password = "xxx";
        $this->charset  = 'utf8mb4';
    }

    function connect(){
        try{
            $connection = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db . ";charset=" . $this->charset;
            $options = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
            ];

            if($this->pdo == null)
                $this->pdo = new PDO($connection, $this->user, $this->password, $options);
    
            return $this->pdo;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            print_r('Error connection: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function getDb(){
        if($this->pdo instanceof PDO){
            return $this->pdo;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Benito. He puesto el código tal y como dices en la class Database, lo demás lo he dejado igual, pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error con la función prepare. No estoy entendiendo bien porque sale este error.

Comment: Te recomiendo que compruebes que la conexión a la base de datos se realiza correctamente. Es decir, que los datos son correctos y el servidor está corriendo. Además, puedes imprimir $dbget->errorInfo() oara ver si ha dado algún error antes de ejecutar la query